# autonomous differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Please suggest me good book of ordinary differential equation in which I can study about autonomous differential equation $y’=f(y), y(x_0)=y_0$in details . Particularly solution behaviour of differential equation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any ODE can be formulated as autonomous ODE. A solar system with all its planets and asteroids can be simulated as an autonomous ODE system. You need to be a little more specific in "study about autonomous differential equation". Certainly Arnol'd's text about the mathematics of classical mechanics is always a good read (without expectation to understand everything at the first go), but also only covers a slice of the topic.

Comment: What are expecting to find in such book? Are you interested in existence and uniqueness conditions? Are you interested in studying chaos? Limit cycles? stability?

Comment: @RodrigoAldana behaviour of solution like monotone, existence and uniqueness, maximum interval of existence of solutions....

Comment: @RodrigoAldana without finding solutions , how to tell nature of solutions.

Comment: Ok, I have modified my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $y$ is a vector function with parameter $x$ and $f$ is an arbitrary non linear function then an explicit solution for $y(x)$ may not be easy to obtain, so books on "solving" differential equations may not be very useful. However, the behavior of the solution can still be studied by looking at the particular form of $f$. Steven Strogatz wrote the fantastic book "Nonlinear dynamics and chaos" where he presents a lot of interesting things one can derive about the solution $y(x)$ without having to obtain its explicit form. In particular, chapter 2 (from the printing of 1994) migth be useful to know if this book is suitable for you. The book covers a little on existence of solutions, oscillators, limit cycles, bifurcations, stability, and chaos.

If you are more interested in general conditions for existence and uniqueness I have used the text "Uniqueness and non-uniqueness criteria for ordinary differential equations" by R. P. Agarwal, which covers many of the conditions for uniqueness of solutions in first-order ODE's, second order, and high order.

Moreover, you may wan't to take a look at Chapter 3 (of third edition) of "Nonlinear systems" by Hassan Khalil. He covers many of the properties one can derive for a nonlinear ODE without obtaining the solution (existence and uniqueness, continuous dependence on initial conditions and parameters, differentiability of solutions and sensitivity among others). However, this book is more inclined into control theory and stability.

Without more context of what you are looking for, this is what I can recommend. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you sir ...